# Bndtools project fails to run

Tags: java, eclipse, bndtools

I have been trying to run Bndtools projects on my Eclipse IDE, but to no success. I have installed Bndtools Via the Eclipse Marketplace, as described [here (*Install Bndtools*)](http://bndtools.org/installation.html#marketplace). I then try to follow this tuitorial as is [(*Bndtools Tutorial*)](http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html#installing-bndtools), but I can't seem to get it to print to console. I have tried various other projects, but to no success. No errors get thrown anywhere.

I should point out that the Bndtools install does not come with all the repositories. I'm particularly missing all **org.apache.felix.dependencymanager** dependencies. I have successfully added them to my eclipse repositories via drag and drop onto the **Build Repositories** bundles group without any errors:

> > org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.annotation-4.0.3
> >     org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.runtime-4.0.2
> >     org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.shell-4.0.3
> >     org.apache.felix.dependencymanager-4.2.0

Why won't my project run as others do? Is there anything else that I have to do before I have a Bndtools project working successfully?

**Eclipse**

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200

**Java:**

java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)